# Using GHC with LLVM 3.2

Tags: llvm, ghc

I have LLVM/opt-3.2 installed along with [llvm-3.2.0.2](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/llvm), and I just installed GHC 7.6.2 from the Ubuntu package. However, when I try to compile ghc with -fllvm -v3, I get the error:

```
*** CodeGen:
*** LlVM CodeGen:
Error (figuring out LLVM version): fd:10: hGetLine: end of file

<no location info>:
    Warning: Couldn't figure out LLVM version!
             Make sure you have installed LLVM
*** LLVM Optimiser:
'opt-3.0' '/tmp/ghc17812_0/ghc17812_0.ll' '-o' '/tmp/ghc17812_0/ghc17812_0.bc' '-mem2reg' '--enable-tbaa=true'
*** Deleting temp files:
...
ghc: could not execute: opt-3.0
```

`opt` is in my path, but the version is 3.2, not 3.0. If it isn't the hackage llvm package that makes GHC look for the proper version of opt, what is it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There seem to be two relevant ghc-tracs for this: [one](http://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/7661) and [two](http://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/7143).

In the latter trac, a user mentioned the options "-pgmlo" and "-pgmlc", which can be found [here](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.3/html/users_guide/options-phases.html).

I was able to fix my problem by adding "-pgmlo opt -pgmlc llc" to the list of GHC options.

As an alternative, you can edit `/usr/lib/ghc/settings` and make sure it has the following lines:

```
("LLVM llc command", "llc"),
("LLVM opt command", "opt")
```

I'd still like to know why GHC tries to find opt-3.0 by default.

Answer (score 6):

Just want to comment that this is still a thing. Instructions for OSX:

```
> brew tap homebrew/dupes
> brew install homebrew/versions/llvm34
```

And keep an alias in my `.bashrc`:

```
alias ghc-llvm="ghc -O2 -fllvm -pgmlo opt-3.4 -pgmlc llc-3.4"
```

Make sure you get `llvm34` and *not* `llvm35`.
I also found that you really want to pass -O2 with LLVM. Without it is very slow.

Comment: What do you actually mean by appending something to your .bashrc, and as of what version of OS X?

Comment: Find out what shell you're using by running ps then read the man page for that shell to learn what script it runs on startup. For most, the shell is bash and it runs $HOME/.bashrc and several other scripts you can use to customize your experience.

Comment: Thanks. As far as I know that's right, but my actual problem was this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24796874/cant-install-diagrams-arithmoi-on-mac