# Can't install diagrams/arithmoi on Mac

Tags: macos, haskell, cabal

I'm trying to install `diagrams` (in a cabal sandbox) and it fails during `arithmoi` installation, giving the following message :

```
Preprocessing library arithmoi-0.4.1.1...

no location info>:
    Warning: Couldn't figure out LLVM version!
         Make sure you have installed LLVM
ghc: could not execute: opt
Failed to install arithmoi-0.4.1.1
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
arithmoi-0.4.1.1 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
diagrams-1.2 depends on arithmoi-0.4.1.1 which failed to install.
diagrams-contrib-1.1.2 depends on arithmoi-0.4.1.1 which failed to install.
```

I'm not sure why I don't have `LLVM` backend installed or why It could execute `opt`.
Any idea ? (I'm using GHC 7.6.3 on OS 10.8)

Comment: Have you installed llvm? If not, get it [here](http://llvm.org/releases/download.html). If you have, is `opt` on your path? Also, you should upgrade your version of GHC. 6.8 is god knows how old.

Comment: I haven't installed llvm. I'll try that. Also what is opt ? I tried many time to upgrade GHC but always endup with library conflict, so I gave up.

Comment: I've installed `LLVM` using `brew install llvm`. Still get the exact same error message.

Comment: @user2407038 about the version, I meant 7.6.3 (but I can't upgrade to 7.8.3)

Comment: It looks like you've found a solution already, but I'm fairly certain (since I don't have a Mac) that brew doesn't add things it installs to your path. You will have look at the brew documentation/configuration to figure out where it places binaries, and put that directory on your path. It also could be that ghc requires a specific version of llvm - but I don't know which one that would.

Comment: @mb14: you need to pass flags to get opt. I did `brew install llvm --all-targets --with-clang --with-lld --with-python && export PATH=/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin:$PATH` and it worked.

Comment: @kgadek I've kind of sorted the problem already but I'll try your solution if I got the problem again

Comment: This is a [known bug with the LLVM/GHC combination](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/9142).  Workarounds are provided by 谷口昂平 and tempestadept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(own answer: I case someone has the same problem) I solved it by downgrading arithmoi to 4.0.4 by adding the following line in may cabal file :

```
build-depend: arithmoi >= 0.4 < 0.4.1.1
```

Had to delete the sandbox and reinstall everything from scratch but worked at the end.

Answer (score 12):

You can build `arithmoi` without LLVM by using `cabal install arithmoi -f -llvm`.

Comment: That doesn't work within a sanbox as I haven't listed arithmoi in my cabal file.

Comment: umm, i think that should be "-f-llvm"

Comment: alternative, if that doesn't work, you can always do --ghc-options="-fasm" as a flag when you cabal instal

Comment: fyi, the `-f -llvm` option to `cabal` disables the llvm flag. https://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/installing-packages.html#controlling-flag-assignments

Comment: I followed kgadek's instructions and what was posted on the following page, but only tempestadept's answer worked. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19342068/using-ghc-with-llvm-3-2/

Answer (score 9):

```
cabal install diagrams --constraint "arithmoi -llvm"
```

There is a way without specifying the range of version.
This worked for me.